# Need help changing product page price magento

Tags: php, css, magento, html

I'm 90% done on a site I'm developing in Magento.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the class of the price span on the product page so I can make that price have an independent style.  I have scoured every page and forum on the entire interwebz, and scanned every line of price.phtml.

Comment: Are you trying to change the style of the price for just one product?

Comment: No, the style of the price for all products on the product page.

Comment: Can you not find it in the CSS and change it? Or are you trying to change the name of the span so you can add different css? If that's the case you may need to edit the PHP.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to change the name of the span to give it it's own class.  However I need help finding what template file to edit to define the price on the product page.  I realize it's probably in the price.phtml file, but I do not know which line calls it for exactly the price on the product page.

Comment: You should change your question to explicitly state that you are trying to find *where* in the code you need to change it to a different class name.

Comment: You must of missed the part where it said 'class of the price span on the product page'.

Answer (score 0):

`price.phtml` is one of the hardest files to change. You can create a model that extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.php`, create a function named `getPrice()`, and do your logic. Vut every time magento needs a price it'll call your method. So, do your logic, and make a condition:

```
if(youcondition)

else
parent::getPrice();
```

That way you won't need to make all the logic of `getPrice` again. This is one of the best ways to do it. But if you want to change price file from magento's core, just go to app/design/default/default/2012/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style of the price class in skin/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_STYLE/css/styles.css and search for '.price'. There are a few diffrent entries for .price class, but you probably require the one that just says '.price'. In the default CSS you can search for '< Product Prices', the line you need to edit is just below that comment.

EDIT:

To edit just the price on the product view, add a new specific css block:

```
.product-view .price {
  *your css changes here* 
}
```

Comment: Again, the price that is being generated was given the same class id on the home page where I have top 4 sellers, product grid, and product view.  For what it's worth, here's the code that is for all prices.

`code` <div class="price-box">
                                                            <span class="product-price" id="product-price-2735">
                                            <span class="price">$22.99</span>                                    </span>
                        
        </div>

Comment: I modified my answer, is this what you were trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the price template(s):

```
template/catalog/product/price.phtml
template/catalog/product/price_msrp.phtml
```

You can modify the classes

```
<span class="price-excluding-tax">
    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
    <span class="price my-price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price+$_weeeTaxAmount,true,false) ?>
    </span>
</span>
```

I would recommend you add in extra classes where needed but leave in the current classes as well to avoid breaking some functionality.

You could then add your styles as required

```
span.price.my-price { color: #ff0000; }
```